# Nodejs res.end() [and other versions of sending response like res.write() etc] not sending complete string, breaking in between

Tags: node.js, html, response

**Scenario**

I am creating a nodejs server, which'll act as a middle server between the actual client and actual server. i.e. I send a request to a website, through my nodejs server, receive the response from actual (website) server, and forward the same to the client (the browser).

Here's part of the code for doing that

```
const cheerio   = require('cheerio');

//#================================================================
// include other files and declare variables
//#================================================================

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {

    //#================================================================
    // some code...
    //#================================================================

    request(options, function(error, response, body){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.writeHead(200, headers);

            if (String(response.headers['content-type']).indexOf('text/html') !== -1){
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);

                //#================================================
                // perform html manipulations
                //#================================================

                //send the html content as response
                res.end($.html());

            }else{
                res.end(body);
            }

        }else{
            res.send({status: 500, error: error});
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works fine, untill I stumble upon this particular website `https://www.voonik.com/recommendations/bright-cotton-a-line-kurta-for-women-blue-printed-bcown-007b-38-1f2073ca`.

If you look at its view source it is more or less like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-in" data-reactid=".mc12nbyapk" data-react-checksum="-2121099716">
<!-- rest of the html code -->
...
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-reactid=".mc12nbyapk.1.1">
window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info = {"agent":"","beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net"...
...
</script></body></html>
```

and when I send this very html in my response object, it sends incomplete html i.e. breaks in between somewhere of the last script tag.

I consoled log the html also and it prints the whole string. But sending the same in response object sends half.

Also tried res.write(); res.send() and storing the html content in a variable then sending that variable, but the outcome is same i.e. incomplete html content.

I was thinking of solution which wouldn't involve writing to and reading from a file. Just directly send the response as you receive it

Comment: Have tried html encoding the response  then decoding it at the client end or escaping the html content may be it is crashing because of some scripts running unsafely

Comment: But in case of some scripts running unsafely, it should have been the case in many other sites i have tested. But only in this particular case, it's not crashing, but the response object is not able to send the whole $.html() string I am sending. And that too breaking at the last script only which just contains an object being assigned to a window object (and that is the actual site's code only)

Comment: So, you're saying that `res.end($.html())` does not send everything that you see when you do `console.log($.html())`?  Are you 100% sure it's not being sent and that there isn't a reading problem on the other end or a content problem such that the reader (the browser) isn't able to properly interpret the data?  Have you verified the packets on the network to know whether it's a sending problem or a reading problem?

Comment: Yes it does not send. And no I don't believe it's a reading problem at the other end because I tried @Codisan 's solution as well, which directly streams the response object, and the client receives whole html in that case. All I am doing is, getting that response, performing manipulations on it, sending the resultant html string back.

Comment: When you do `res.writeHead(200, headers);`, where do `headers` come from?  You don't show any code for that.  Could some of the headers (like `content-length`) be wrong?

Comment: Yes @Codisan just pointed out the same, it was the `content-length` that messed up. As for the headers, they were the original response headers I got from the actual website server and as it so happened that since I was manipulating the html content, the `content-length` had it be recalculated or not be included at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you manipulate the target server response contents, the content length is changed, so you must recalculate the content length and rewrite the content-length header, or just delete the content-length header,

put this code `delete headers['content-length']`, before `res.writeHead(200, headers);` this line.

Comment: But I have many manipulations also to perform on the html, before I can send back the response, thus I cannot directly stream the response. This is the reason I am using `cheerio`

Comment: Hi @Codisan on another note, is your code able to load a website like `https://www.quikr.com/electronics-appliances/lg-1.5-ton-window-a-c-with-1-year-warranty-delivery-in-condition+mumbai+W0QQAdIdZ307788934` ? Because I tried it with both, my server code as well as a headless browser like puppeteer, and in both cases it fails to load. It recognizes that the request is an automated one.

Comment: after you manipulate the target server response contents, the content length is changed, so you must recalculate the content length and rewrite the content-length header, or just delete the content-length header

Comment: for the original question, I encounter the same question before by using request module,  `res.writeHead(200, headers);` this line is wrong, put `delete headers['content-length']` before this line

Comment: yes that is correct! Thank you. Pls edit your answer and include this comment

Comment: Hi @Codisan [strictly speaking it's ok if you havn't got time or don't want to respond to this] Here are two URLs `https://www.flipkart.com/four-star-popular-plus-fs-010-dry-iron/p/itmf2ds62cuzdvve` and `https://www.quikr.com/electronics-appliances/lg-1.5-ton-window-a-c-with-1-year-warranty-delivery-in-condition+mumbai+W0QQAdIdZ307788934` for which my proxy fails. Also tried your previous code (the one using bridge) and that too didn't work. Can you tell me what is going wrong in these?